# convert arraylist data from object / float to int to use in a method

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arraylist in a class that I store number in. The method in the class that adds data to the arraylist  takes one float parameter - this is because some of the data is float and some is integer.

I need to extract some of the data with a method and convert it to an Int but cant work out how to. Ive tried various was of casting etc but because it is objects in the arraylist I cant get it working.

(So if this isnt sounding too clear , ive been at this for 8 hours straight so brain is a bit fried now)

For example , the arraylist is called subjectsResults and Ive tried:

```
numberOfA = (Integer)subjectsResults.get(1);
```

where numberOfA is an Int (i know where the index is of the data also - that is why I reference 1 directly)

Ive tried using toString and parseInt and things like this:

```
numberOfA = (Integer.parseInt((String)subjectsResults.get(1)));
```

How can I achieve this - i need to extract the number from index(1) to use in a switch/case statement to show a menu choice

Comment: So it is an arraylist of `Float`s?

Comment: well i didnt use autoboxing to specify just declared it ArrayList subjectsResults = new ArrayList(); but when i add anything to it the line in teh method is subjectsResults.add(results);    - where results is a float variable. So i think im right in saying it is just an arraylist of objects yes?

Comment: Is there is any error?

Comment: ive been trying many different things so i cant give specifics sorry, but I have had various usually errors saying you cant cast a float to an int , or object o an int etc. I have managed to have teh class compiled sometimes and get runtime errors when the display method is called also.

Comment: Obviously you can't cast Float to Integer. Use `instanceof` operator for checking its type before down casting from object to Integer. As you said that you have stored an int at index 1 then how come it is possible to have a float at index 1.

Comment: i havent actually stored an in at index 1 , althought the original data is an int, due to the fact that I call a method with a float parameter to populate the arraylist it ends up being a float. Ideally I would like to store some ints and some floats in the same arraylist but obviously i cant - hence the need for the conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways of solving this, one straight forward approach would be this:

```
Object value = subjectsResults.get(1); 
if (value instanceof Integer) {
  numberOfA = (Integer) value;
} else if (value instanceof Float) {
  numberOfA = ((Float) value).intValue();
} else {
  handle this unusual case
}
```

The even cleverer solution is to use the common superclass `Number`. Both `Integer` and `Float` are subclasses of `Number` - and they therefore share the method `intValue()`.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Snippet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // define test data
        List<Number> subjectsResults = new ArrayList<>();
        subjectsResults.add((int) 50);
        subjectsResults.add((float) 33.333f);

        // create target list
        List<Integer> subjectsNumbers = new ArrayList<>();

        // iterate over input
        for (Number number : subjectsResults) {

            // use method "intValue", which is available for all "Number"-objects
            subjectsNumbers.add(number.intValue());
        }

        System.out.println(subjectsNumbers);
    }

}
```

The output in console:

```
[50, 33]
```

Comment: this looks like a good path to follow , although all values will be stored as float i think  (because the method that adds the data to arraylist , the parameter is a float) but your code would work regardless. thanks i will try using this

Comment: Just to update, the first code above, with some edits , worked out perfect for me thanks slartidan

Answer (score 0):

Similar solution to slartidan except I don't like type checking so will be using generics instead.

```
 public class FloatAndInt {
    private static <T extends Number> void addItemToArray(final T item,final List numberList) {
        numberList.add(item);
    }
```

```
private static void iterateArrayList(final List<Number> numberList) {
    for (Number n:numberList) {
       System.out.println(n.intValue());

    }
 }
 public static void main(String args[]) {
    List<Number> numberList = new ArrayList<Number>();
    addItemToArray(2,numberList);
    addItemToArray(4.3f,numberList);
    //addItemToArray(Long.MAX_VALUE, numberList);
    //addItemToArray(Double.MAX_VALUE, numberList);
    iterateArrayList(numberList);
  }
```

}

Output:

```
2
4
```